# Subclassing List<T> doesnt retain lists functionality

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have created a subclass of a generic list so that I could implement a new interface

```
public class CustomersCollection : List<Customer>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
...
}
```

When I change the field definition to the new class (see example of old and new lines below)  I get all sorts of compile errors on things that should exist in the original list.

```
public CustomersCollection Customers { get; set; } 
public void Sample()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Customers.Where(x=>x.condition).First().ToString());
}
```

Why does CustomersCollection does not inherit the IQueryable, IEnumerable interface implementations for List?

The official error is:

> 'CustomersCollection' does not contain
>   a definition for 'Where' and no
>   extension method 'Where' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'CustomersCollection' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

---

It turns out that the custom implementation of IEnumerable causes all the extension methods that apply to IEnumerable to fail. Whats going on here?

Comment: Are you sure it makes any kind of sense at all to inherit from a class that implements `IEnumerable<Customer>` but override this to implement `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`? Wouldn't it be better to simply add a method that returns `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` to avoid complicating things?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The extension methods *are* available to a class that inherits from `List<T>`. Perhaps you need to add `using System.Linq;` to your code file? Also check that you have a reference to `System.Core.dll`.

**Edit**

Since you have `List<U>` and `IEnumerable<T>` being inherited/implemented by the same class, you need to provide the type when you use the extension methods. Example:

```
CustomerCollection customers = new CustomerCollection();
customers.Add(new Customer() { Name = "Adam" });
customers.Add(new Customer() { Name = "Bonita" });
foreach (Customer c in customers.Where<Customer>(c => c.Name == "Adam"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
}
```

... based on

```
class Customer { public string Name { get; set; } }    

class Foo { }

class CustomerCollection : List<Customer>, IEnumerable<Foo>
{
    private IList<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

    public new IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return foos.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Where` is not inherited, but it requires implementation of `IEnumerable`, which here is provided through inheritance.  Agreed that `CustomersCollection` has everything needed to be used in LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that is not the solution.  This code was working with List<Customer>.  As soon as I change it to CustomerCollection, the code fails to compile.  There are no missing references or namespace imports.  Thats why I'm confused.